# Nodejs function to return string to main program

Tags: node.js, callback

I am having an issue with turning nodejs code into a function that returns a string so I can use that string later in the code.

When I turn this into a function, I dont have anything returning.

I'm not sure if it is a callback issue, because I would think I should have a return of undefined.

Not sure what the issue is.

```
 var request = require('request-promise');

    let authtoken;  

function remedyLogin() {
var uri = 'https://test-XXX.com';

var _include_headers = function(body, response, resolveWithFullResponse) {
  return {'headers': response.headers, 'data': body};
};

var options = {
  method: 'POST',
  uri: uri,
  json: true,
  transform: _include_headers,
  body: { "username":"XXXXXXX", "password":"XXXXXXXXXXXXXx"
    },
}

request(options)
    .then(function (parsedBody) {
        console.log("post success");
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        console.log("post failed");
    });

return request(options)
.then(function(response) {

var result = JSON.stringify(response.headers);
var res = result.match(/{\"authentication-token":".*","content-type/);
stringgy = res[0].substring(25);
authtoken = stringgy.substring(0, stringgy.length-17);
console.log(authtoken);
return authtoken;

});

}

var foo = RemedyLogin;
console.log(foo);
```

This code below works fine and I'm returned  an auth code as follows.

```
post success
/DwG7gAAAAAAAAAA4RZPA8x0Ny3ztp0ImAAk8M0bCLDkUzwA0HNG8CSAxtws3QQu353Gdb3/stXd0o
PMgh7Wgaq99rUOa1whKC0TOfFCtD8c9SZHWlyX9Do7CxdffOeGtMphw+EiC8R/JEnPxJJUq/g+eUlg
bDcB2S0w2w2XGNlJ/3HNM4rIpbn+me9EK9xNMkI2F+WrzkWMnQaUWQn/VTi6l84eQR1CuPdDrn6r4t
MADTFlWYpFL7maqqYAmEzYBahIQ+uRwautvBVwyQJSstV8xTbVso2bhe7VI+ms/bI0BR4yVaJQzg/9
rAxj2QbAWsRowT3p22y3BmWzkXpgGT2QcU6SKr2/PyuWf1Lo9xMTtgZujofA+iuPwOv0zAHL9wg5qY
AbcQYS9RKSj1FltMIMgsvKVJlXhIKAQLih4kVaPklMhF/x4qYg5q8GuDbm0IyicrxJFPISpe2ba8GI
MqurgGUsdiaqNrRSXjevbuyeuJ7nA+TLSGUG0hYxg6OT9CNVfJ6It8hWPvD/OtFhAncVgA
```

Here is the code.

```
 var request = require('request-promise');
    var uri = 'https://test-orchestrator.lmig.com/baocdp/rest/login';


    var _include_headers = function(body, response, resolveWithFullResponse) {
      return {'headers': response.headers, 'data': body};
    };

var options = {
  method: 'POST',
  uri: uri,
  json: true,
  transform: _include_headers,
  body: { "username":"sahst_trap_parser_ao", "password":"cgSW68eJexsPet"
    },
}

request(options)
    .then(function (parsedBody) {
        console.log("post success");
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        console.log("post failed");
    });

return request(options)
.then(function(response) {

var result = JSON.stringify(response.headers);
var res = result.match(/{\"authentication-token":".*","content-type/);
stringgy = res[0].substring(25);
var authtoken = stringgy.substring(0, stringgy.length-17);
console.log(authtoken);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you called the remedyLogin function incorrectly. Try to change this code:

```
var foo = RemedyLogin;
console.log(foo);
```

to

```
remedyLogin().then(foo => console.log(foo));
```